# Ainda devo salvar arquivos como .HTM ou apenas como .HTML

Tags: html, html5, webserver

Apesar dos dois serem interpretados igualmente pelo Browser me parece que a extensão .HTM caiu em desuso. Ainda devo salvar meus arquivos como .HTM ou devo sempre optar pelo .HTML?

Parece que nos primórdios os arquivos eram .html mesmo, mas por causa do Windows foram obrigados a passar para .htm (por ter apenas 3 dígitos na extensão), mas atualmente só vejo .html novamente.

Inclusive fiz um teste no server local e coloquei dois **index**, um **index.html** e outro **index.htm**, e para minha surpresa o index.html teve preferencia tanto no Wamp quanto no Vertrigo. Ou seja o arquivo .HTML tem preferencia... Também me parece que alguns webservers não se dão bem com .htm

Então ficou a dúvida. Não devemos mais salvar arquivos como .HTM pensando na longevidade, mantenabilidade, versatilidade e interação da aplicação com outros sistemas? Ou pode deixa como .HTM que "está tranquilo"?

***OBS:*** Ainda lembre que o Dreamwever na época da Macromidia tinha por default salvar em .htm

Comment: Você ainda usa a extensão HTM?! Isso era uma limitação do DOS, o correto sempre foi HTML (a web surgiu em ambiente UNIX, que sempre suportou extensões de qualquer tamanho).

Comment: @bfavaretto sempre trabalhei em ambiente Windows e até pouco tempo via bastante coisa .htm, inclusive a maioria dos softwares ainda dão a opção de salvar direto em .htm, logo, porque não... Ai fiquei na dúvida, mesmo parecendo algo básico

Comment: A preferência do index se é html, php, htm é configurado no próprio servidor, não? no Apache por exemplo tem `<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php4 index.php3 index.cgi index.pl index.html index.htm index.shtml index.phtml
</IfModule>`

Comment: Legal @JohnDoe veja que no seu exemplo ainda tem o .htm, mas parece que tem servers que nem aceitam mais ele como extensão válida. Eu não sabia como era gerenciada essa hierarquia dentro do server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe diferenças, pode-se usar tanto .htm quanto .html.  A preferência é de cunho pessoal.

Porém, dependendo das configurações do seu servidor, ele pode preferir como wealcome page o index.htm ou index.html ou até ambos, ou até algo como index.php.

Eu prefiro usar a versão longa, .html.

Fonte:
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/internet/difference-between-htm-and-html/